# how to track and modify an in-flight oracle query before execution?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

My Application is sending below query to Oracle.

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DATE > (SYSDATE - 1) order by employee_id

I cannot change this query from the application. I am looking for a way for oracle to monitor the queries, change it to below query format and return the result.

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DATE > (SYSDATE - 1) and Currently_employed = 'YES' order by employee_id

Thank You.
Subrat

Comment: Why not just change the app to send the correct query?

Comment: The query is fired from a Application product which is out of support now. So I cannot modify that.

Answer (score 3):

If the application can connect to the database as a different user then the table owner, you could also implement a Virtual Private Database policy to modify the query in-flight. See here:

- https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/virtual-private-databases

You could also, if the application is connecting as a separate user, create a view as suggested by @ekochergin, and have a synonym "EMPLOYEE" in the application's user schema point to the view in the data owner's schema.

If the application is connecting as the data owner, your options are much more limited. Renaming the table and replacing it with a view as suggested would be the easiest option. If you've got a lot of money to invest in Oracle's Database Application Firewall appliance you could also modify the query in-flight with a security policy there.

Answer (score 1):

You might needed to rename employee table to somewhat like "EMP_TABLE" and create a view named "EMPLOYEE" using

```
create view employee as select * from emp_table where currently_employed = 'YES';
```

Please test it against a test instance before implementing on live

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL Translation Framework if you only need to convert a small number of statements. If you need to modify many statements then you should look into the options described in the other answers, such as Virtual Private Database, views, or synonyms.

For this sample schema:

```
create table employee
(
    employee_id number,
    hire_date date,
    currently_employed varchar2(3)
);

insert into employee values(1, sysdate, 'NO');
insert into employee values(1, sysdate, 'YES');

commit;
```

Create the following translator profile and then create the specific translation:

```
begin
    dbms_sql_translator.create_profile('EMPLOYEE_TRANSLATOR_PROFILE');

    dbms_sql_translator.register_sql_translation
    (
        profile_name    => 'EMPLOYEE_TRANSLATOR_PROFILE',
        sql_text        => q'[SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE HIRE_DATE > (SYSDATE - 1) order by employee_id]',
        translated_text => q'[SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE HIRE_DATE > (SYSDATE - 1) and Currently_employed = 'YES' order by employee_id]'
    );
end;
/
```

The translation profile must be enabled in each session. Since you have no control over the application, you can create a logon profile that will automatically run the commands to enable the translation:

```
--Logon trigger that enables profiles.
--I'm not sure why, but you must create this trigger as SYS.
create or replace trigger sys.logon_trg
after logon on database
--Add your username here:
when (user in ('JHELLER'))
begin
    execute immediate 'alter session set sql_translation_profile = jheller.employee_translator_profile';
    execute immediate q'[alter session set events = '10601 trace name context forever, level 32']';
end;
/
```

Now, when the application runs the original query that would normally return two rows, it will run the second query that only returns one row:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE HIRE_DATE > (SYSDATE - 1) order by employee_id;

EMPLOYEE_ID HIRE_DATE CUR
----------- --------- ---
          1 12-FEB-21 YES
```

But be careful of tiny syntax changes that will prevent the translation. For example, if `SELECT` is changed to `select`, the query will not be replaced and will return two rows again:

```
SQL> select * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE HIRE_DATE > (SYSDATE - 1) order by employee_id;

EMPLOYEE_ID HIRE_DATE CUR
----------- --------- ---
          1 12-FEB-21 YES
          1 12-FEB-21 NO
```